# I want to upload objects to AWS S3 buckets which are of size greater than 500mb.

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a web application using angular js (for UI) and java (@back end) in which i am creating a user interface through which a user can manipulate  data in S3 buckets. I need to upload data to buckets which are of size about 500 mb. I am currently being able to send 5mb chunks of data to servlets but i am not able to combine those chunked objects to upload my original data to S3. Is there any alternative way for achieving this?

Comment: You can use this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) or you can upload via s3 commandline tool http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/minio/minio-java. It has minimal set of abstracted API's implementing most commonly used S3 calls.

Here is an example of streaming upload.

```
import io.minio.MinioClient;
import io.minio.errors.ClientException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PutObject {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException, ClientException {
    System.out.println("PutObject app");

    // Set s3 endpoint, region is calculated automatically
    MinioClient s3Client = new MinioClient("https://s3.amazonaws.com", "YOUR-ACCESSKEYID", "YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11 * 1024 * 1024; i++) {
      builder.append('a');
    }
    // create object
    s3Client.putObject("mybucket", "my/object", "application/octet-stream", 11 * 1024 * 1024, new ByteArrayInputStream(builder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
  }
}
```

putObject() here is a fully managed single function call for file sizes over 5MB it automatically does multipart internally and once complete Amazon S3 will present it as a single object. You can resume a failed upload as well and it will start from where its left off by verifying previously upload parts.

With this putObject() you can upload upto 5TB single large object (5TB is maximum single object size on Amazon S3)